# When I added my player1 and player2 classes I keep getting the error TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

The error that I am getting is

```
File "C:\Users\Nicholas\PycharmProjects\MortalKombat\Fighting.py", line 149, in main
allsprites.draw(screen)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

Earlier I was getting a video system not initialized error and posted a question for that which lead me to a problem in this program that caused that error in my main program.

I fixed that error but then the error above arose when I added player1, player2, and scoreboard to the pygame.sprites.Group(). The code for Fighting.py is below. I am doing

```
allsprites.draw(screen)
```

and I thought that screen

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,400))
```

was a pygame.Surface argument but I am not sure what str means.

```
import pygame


class Scoreboard(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.lives = 5
        self.score = 0
        self.timeRem = 60
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 50)
        self.RED = (255, 0, 0)
        self.GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.text = ("%d" % self.timeRem)
        if self.timeRem > 20:
            self.image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, self.GREEN)
        else:
            self.image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, self.RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (450,25)


class Player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.player = "none"
        self.player1Txt = open("Player1", "r")
        self.image = self.player1Txt.read()
        self.player1Txt.close()
        self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking0000.png")
        self.player = self.player.convert()
        self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
        self.rect = self.player.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (150,100)
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if Player2.rect.centerx > self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter +=1
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
                self.rect.centerx += 5
            elif Player2.rect.centerx < self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter = 7
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
                self.rect.centerx += 5
                self.counter -= 1
            elif Player2.rect.centerx == self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter +=1
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
                self.rect.centerx += 5


class Player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.player = "none"
        self.player2Txt = open("Player2", "r")
        self.image = self.player2Txt.read()
        self.player2Txt.close()
        self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking0000.png")
        self.player = self.player.convert()
        self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
        self.rect = self.player.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (150,100)
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            if Player1.rect.centerx > self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter +=1
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
                self.rect.centerx += 5
            elif Player1.rect.centerx < self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter = 7
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))
                self.rect.centerx += 5
                self.counter -= 1
            elif Player1.rect.centerx == self.rect.centerx:
                self.counter +=1
                self.player = pygame.image.load(self.image + "/walking000" + str(self.counter) + ".png")
                self.player = self.player.convert()
                self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100,100))

                self.rect.centerx += 5


def main():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 400))

    background = pygame.image.load("arena.png")
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, screen.get_size())

    scoreboard = Scoreboard()
    player1 = Player1()
    player2 = Player2()

    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allsprites.add(scoreboard)
    allsprites.add(player1)
    allsprites.add(player2)

    counter = 0
    counter2 = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True

    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)
        counter +=1

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

        if counter%30 == 0:
            counter2 += 1
            if counter2 >= 60:
                scoreboard.timeRem = 0
            else:
                scoreboard.timeRem -= 1

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

        allsprites.update()
        allsprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So why are you opening up a txt file?

Comment: Hi there. Please keep titles informative, and refrain from adding any form of urgent/ASAP begging anywhere in questions. Adding this does not get you an answer any faster, but it does cause editors some extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look and I think this piece of code is causing the error:

```
self.player1Txt = open("Player1", "r")
    self.image = self.player1Txt.read()
    self.player1Txt.close()
```

and

```
self.player2Txt = open("Player2", "r")
    self.image = self.player2Txt.read()
    self.player2Txt.close()
```

Now I don't know why you are making the program read the text file but the problem is that when creating a self.image you have to do it in a format like this:

```
self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
```

If you want to use an image file you could also do something like this:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, (width, height))
```

as I think this is what you were attempting to do with the text files.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was reading the file that was created from a different file but I used a different methods since you said that was the problem and that fixed the error. Thanks